# Which service of Google provide redirector.googlevideo.com link?

Tags: google, video, video-streaming

I see some websites use redirector Google video link like this:

```
https://redirector.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?requiressl=yes&id=a511c599c7e0fcf7&itag=22&source=webdrive&ttl=transient&app=explorer&ip=2001:19f0:6000:9533:5400:ff:fe25:9d2&ipbits=32&expire=1468959609&sparams=requiressl%2Cid%2Citag%2Csource%2Cttl%2Cip%2Cipbits%2Cexpire&signature=4A2A62D0C56E513362B0892DF8ACA60BECB66F07.73B8A56D4B309CBB20DD7B2A79696F18BF7C5D11&key=ck2&mm=31&mn=sn-a5mekn7r&ms=au&mt=1468944541&mv=m&nh=IgpwcjAyLmxheDAyKgkxMjcuMC4wLjE&pl=38
```

in the src to embed video, if I access that link in browser it returns

```
https://r2---sn-8qj-i5oel.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?requiressl=yes&id=a511c599c7e0fcf7&itag=22&source=webdrive&ttl=transient&app=explorer&ip=14.177.224.90&ipbits=32&expire=1468959609&sparams=expire,id,ip,ipbits,itag,mm,mn,ms,mv,pcm2cms,pl,requiressl,source,ttl&signature=25725FB95054AED20C329EEFF7249049F9BE3F1B.5664E210DC28086EC0EDBE12AD70C6269B64848D&key=cms1&pl=20&cms_redirect=yes&mm=31&mn=sn-8qj-i5oel&ms=au&mt=1468944541&mv=m&pcm2cms=yes
```

but it seems to be expired in a limited time.

Where does the video actually host? How could I create a redirector link like above? Is redirector.googlevideo.com an api of Google?

Answer (score -1):

I'm pretty sure it's a Google Drive video but they encrypt it to make it look like above.